# Vuex store does not update component collection when pushing from mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to push `task` to `state.tasks` variable array in store module via mutation. When I'm fetching all tasks and assign it to a `state.tasks` everything works perfect and appears on the screen, but when I'm pushing `task` to a `state.tasks` store is not adding it on a view.(I checked it via console.log task was pushed to state.tasks in mutation. No errors).
I've left info below. What am I doing wrong?

State:

```
const state = {
    tasks: [],
};
```

Actions:
The `tasks` is api service which I import `import tasks from '../../api/tasks';`

```
const actions = {
    getTasks({commit}) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            tasks.getTasks().then(response => {
                commit('setTasks', response.data.data);
                resolve(response);
            }).catch(error => {
                reject(error);
            })
        });
    },

    createTask({commit}, text) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            tasks.createTask(text).then(response => {
                commit('createTask', response.data.data);
                resolve(response);
            }).catch(error => {
                reject(error);
            })
        });
    }
};
```

Mutation:

```
const mutations = {
    setTasks(state, tasks) {
        state.tasks = tasks;
    },
    createTask(state, task) {
        state.tasks.push(task);
        console.log(state.tasks);
    }
};
```

Getters:

```
const getters = {
    undoneTasks(state) {
        return state.tasks.filter(task => task.done == false);
    },
    doneTasks(state) {
        return state.tasks.filter(task => task.done == true);
    }
};
```

In component:

```
mounted() {
            store.dispatch('getTasks').catch(error => {
                if (error.response) {
                    this.checkResponse(error.response.status);
                }
            });
        },

methods: {
        createTask() {
            store.dispatch('createTask', this.taskText)
                .then(() => {
                    this.taskText = '';
                }).catch(error => {
                if (error.response) {
                    this.checkResponse(error.response.status);
                }
            });
        }
 },
computed: {
            ...mapGetters({
                tasks: 'undoneTasks'
            }),
        },
```

**Updated**

In module actions `tasks` is api service which I import `import tasks from '../../api/tasks';`
Also I tried to `state.tasks.pop()` and It worked, I thought that is because of incorrect incoming data, but I checked again and it really pushing it to state.tasks but component does not react...

Comment: How are you pushing items onto `state.tasks` when it is declared null instead of an empty array?

Comment: @Stephen i have another action that fetch all tasks which are array

Comment: If you initialize `state.tasks` as an empty array your `undoneTasks` getter can be simplified to just `return state.tasks.filter(task => task.done === false)` and it fixes the issue of that getter having different return types (array or boolean)

Comment: @Stephen I checking state.tasks because I use promise and without if statement error appears. Thanks, but I have different problem.

Comment: @NickSynev in your `createTask` action, in this line: `tasks.createTask(text).then(response)`, the `tasks` variable is defined nowhere

Comment: @sovalina Its defined I updated my question. First I get all tasks and they are in state.tasks. Second I want to push to state.tasks a single task and it not updating on the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, guys so I figured it out. Thanks for all support and answers. So I have tried manually set object for push in mutation.

```
createTask(state, task) {
        const taskObj = {id: task.id, text: task.text, done: false};
        state.tasks.push(taskObj);
    }
```

And It worked, the problem was because of `done` field that was coming as null from server. I think I should read more info about vuex, but it is very strange...

Answer (score 0):

I would set tasks as an empty array to start with and only allow the `createTask` mutation to add tasks to the array. I've recreated your code and it works fine, though I am not using the spread `mapGetters`.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
 state: {
   tasks: [],
  },
  actions: {
   createTask({commit}, task) {
     return new Promise((res, rej) => {
       setTimeout(() => {
         commit('createTask', task);
          res(true);
        }, 1000);
      });
    },
  },
  mutations: {
   createTask(state, task) {
     state.tasks.push(task);
    },
  },
  getters: {
   undoneTasks: state => state.tasks.filter(t => t.done === false),
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  data: {
  },
  methods: {
   toggle: function(todo){
     todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  },
  computed: {
   tasks() {
     return this.$store.getters.undoneTasks;
    }
  },
  created() {
   this.$store.dispatch('createTask', { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false });
    this.$store.dispatch('createTask', { text: "Learn Vue", done: false });
    setTimeout(() => 
   [{ text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: false },
     { text: "Build something awesome", done: false }].map(t => this.$store.dispatch('createTask', t)), 1000);
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in tasks">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          v-on:change="toggle(todo)"
          v-bind:checked="todo.done">

        <del v-if="todo.done">
          {{ todo.text }}
        </del>
        <span v-else>
          {{ todo.text }}
        </span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: No, that's just for the checkbox to call the toggle method.

Comment: I set tasks to empty array and change computed like your, but it didn't help(